# display:inline property not working

Tags: html, css

I am having an unordered list where I've given `display:inline` for `li` to view the list horizontally, but I am not able to view it horizontally. Here is my code:

```
ul li{
min-height:310px;
background:#FFF;
width:330px;
display:inline;
margin-left:15px;
}
<ul>
    <li><div>Something</div></li>
    <li><div>Something</div></li>
    <li><div>Something</div></li>
    <li><div>Something</div></li>
</ul>
```

Note: I should not use `float:left` or `float:right`. So I preferred for display property.

Comment: Why can't you use float?

Comment: Works fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/p78b7/

Comment: do you have elements inside of `li` that are block elements ?

Comment: Try using `!important`

Comment: @97ldave It's obvious this is a case of a rule being overwritten.

Comment: !important is the bed practice in css

Comment: That may be the case, I'm just working with what the question provides. You could use !important to check that it is a rule being overwritten, but do not use !important - very bad practice as @Rohit Azad says

Comment: also `!important` would not help if the html code e.g. looks like this `<li><div>text</div></li>` because `display:inline` is only applied to `li` and the  `div` is still a block element. but to detect the problem `!important` could help.

Comment: @t.niese:you're right. To fix that what should I do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested it on all browsers and this is working. Anyway if you have been suffering from this problem add `display: inline-block;` to your parent element.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

I would suspect you have another class which is over ridding or you're not referencing the desired class (typo).

Or, the fault is with a browser setting? Check that it fails in all browsers.

Comment: My li is like "<li><div></div></li>" I found this might be the problem. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Why do you have this if you're applying any property to the div?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your css with a ul and it is working fine (

elements are displayed horizontaly).

Maybe you have some other rule overwriting this one, so try using !important as so:

```
display:inline !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

In chromium all looks fine

Olivera Kovacevic point to good *fast* decision which resolve your problem but later you may will have a lot of problems with such styles.

Try to implement [this style of ccssing](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/16/a-new-front-end-methodology-bem/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#navcontainer ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#navcontainer ul li {
    display: inline;
}

#navcontainer ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #036;
}

#navcontainer ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #369;
}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/firstcss.css" />
<div id="navcontainer">
            <ul>    
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Milk</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Eggs</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Cheese</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Vegetables</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Fruit</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: But li is like "<li><div>Some Text</div></li>"

Comment: #navlist li { display:inline }
#navlist div { display:inline } also put like this way..

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need `white-space:nowrap` on your `ul`

`ul { white-space:nowrap;}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the `div`elements are still block elements.
That is the reason why they are not ordered horizontally. you need to make them to `inline-block` (if you want to be able to set e.g. height or padding for them) otherwise you could set a simple `inline` to them.

the  `min-height` and `width` for your `li` do not have any effect cause you define the `li` as `inline` if you want to use this for the `li` you also should apply the `inline-block` rule to the `li`

**css**

```
ul li{
    min-height:310px;
    background:#FFF;
    width:330px;
    display:inline;
    margin-left:15px;
}

//cross browser inline-block (the order in this rule is important so that it will work cross browser)
li div {
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    *vertical-align: auto;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li><div>Something</div></li>
    <li><div>Something</div></li>
    <li><div>Something</div></li>
    <li><div>Something</div></li>
</ul>
```